# trouble with Levi-Civita symbol from physics-package in Maple

Tags: maple

I try to simplify the next expression:

```
Simplify(LeviCivita[4, sigma, lambda, rho]*LeviCivita[4, xi, eta, mu]*g_[rho, mu]*qp[sigma]*q[lambda]*qp[xi]*q[eta])
```

Maple gives answer: 
  -2*q[lambda]*q[`~lambda`]*qp[sigma]*qp[`~sigma`]+2*q[`~alpha`]*q[`~xi`]*qp[alpha]*qp[xi]

In reality it is incorrect answer, because indices must run over 1,2,3 but not 1,2,3,4!

SumOverRepeatedIndices(%) confirms that maple mistakes.

my preamble is:

```
with(Physics)

Setup(mathematicalnotation = true);
Coordinates(X);

Setup(spaceindices = lowercaselatin)

Setup(tensors = q[mu](X))

PDEtools:-declare(q(X))

Setup(tensors = qp[mu](X))

PDEtools:-declare(qp(X))
```

Answer (score 0):

Offical response:

This is fixed in Maple 2017. The updates of the Physics package, including fixes and the new material being developed are distributed at the Maplesoft R&D Physics webpage.

This Maplesoft R&D Physics webpage also includes updates for Maple 2016 that I recommend, containing fixes and Physics developments that entered Maple 2017, but the last update for Maple 2016 happened Apr/15. Only updates for the current release get posted every week. A workaround in Maple 2016 for this example you posted is to use SumOverRepeatedIndices, as you indicated.